# tput from initrd

Tags: initrd, tput

I have a script that uses tput and runs in a initrd. Specifically I'm using `tput -T linux [sc|rc|ed] > /dev/tty0` to overwrite multiple lines.

When I run in a qemu vm, it works perfectly. When I run it on a real machine, it doesn't overwrite the lines.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

I copied `/lib/terminfo/l/linux` into the initrd, and I ran `tput -T linux clear > /dev/tty0` at the start of the script.